# Unable to open link using react-native-webview IOS

Tags: reactjs, react-native, payment-gateway, react-native-webview

My issue is the following...

I have a payment gateway link which is displayed within an iframe.
From this iframe I can select paypal as a payment type when the CTA is pressed it will provide a link ***https://ppp-test.safecharge.com/ppp/blank.html?ssid=9fb*** this is provided via a pop up window in a web scenario however it is presented in **onNavigationStateChange**. From this generated link it will head to the paypal authentication screen.
The issue is that the first link will open no problem but will get stuck in a loading state with no network output... The only error I have been able to log is the following.

> [CoreServices] Failed to open URL
> https://ppp-test.safecharge.com/ppp/blank.html?ssid=9f*** Error
> Domain=FBSOpenApplicationServiceErrorDomain Code=1 "The request to
> open "com.apple.mobilesafari" failed."
> UserInfo={BSErrorCodeDescription=RequestDenied,
> NSUnderlyingError=0x6000021b22b0 {Error
> Domain=FBSOpenApplicationErrorDomain Code=3 "Application com.***.****
> is neither visible nor entitled, so may not perform un-trusted user
> actions." UserInfo={BSErrorCodeDescription=Security,
> NSLocalizedFailureReason=Application com.bede.bededemo is neither
> visible nor entitled, so may not perform un-trusted user actions.}},
> NSLocalizedDescription=The request to open "com.apple.mobilesafari"
> failed., FBSOpenApplicationRequestID=0xc1ff,
> NSLocalizedFailureReason=The request was denied by service delegate
> (SBMainWorkspace) for reason: Security ("Application
> com.***.identifier is neither visible nor entitled, so may not perform
> un-trusted user actions").}

```
<WebView
  testID="deposit-webview"
  injectedJavaScript='window.addEventListener("message", function (event) { window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage(event.data)});true;'
  style={styles.webview}
  javaScriptEnabled
  onMessage={handleMessage}
  javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically
  onLoadStart={(e) =>
    console.log('WebView Load Start: ', e.nativeEvent)
  }
  onLoadEnd={(e) => console.log('WebView Load End: ', e.nativeEvent)}
  onError={handleWebViewError}
  onHttpError={handleWebViewError}
  onOpenWindow={(e: any) => console.log(e)}
  source={{ uri: depositUrl }}
  originWhitelist={['http://', 'https://', 'paylado:']}
  onNavigationStateChange={(e: any) => {
    console.log(e);
    if (e.url.includes('blank.html?')) {
      try {
        Linking.canOpenURL(e.url).then((supported) => {
          if (supported) Linking.openURL(e.url);
        });
      } catch (e) {
        console.log("can't open this url", e);
      }
    } else if (
      playerDepositParams?.paymentGateway === 'Paylado' &&
      e.url !== depositUrl
    ) {
      onDepositSuccess(remoteReference);
    }
  }}
  onShouldStartLoadWithRequest={(request) => {
    if (request.url.startsWith('paylado:')) {
      try {
        Linking.canOpenURL(request.url).then((supported) => {
          if (supported) Linking.openURL(request.url);
        });
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(
          "Failed to launch paylado app, it probably isn't installed on the device"
        );
      }
    }

    return !request.url.startsWith('paylado:');
  }}
/>
```